# JavaFX Loop through array and find a match, otherwise try again

Tags: java, javafx

I have a GUI based e-store project. I read in a file and parse through it and saved it into an array.
The file format is like so: *11111, "title", 9.90*

11111 is the book id, "title" is title, and 9.90 is the price.

I currently have 3 classes in my project. 1 class for Input/Output, 1 class for the Book store GUI code, and another for pop-up boxes when specific buttons are clicked.

In the GUI code, I check read the file into String[] fileArray and then loop through it until there is a match (with TextField input *String bookIds = bookIdinput.getText()*)

I'm able to successfully get a match and go on with the rest of the code, but when there isn't a match, I get an error: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException at windowDisplay.lambda$start$3(windowDisplay.java:###) 
which is this line of code `for(int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++)`

If there isn't a match, then it should show a pop-up box saying that bookID isn't found.

Below is some of the GUI code

```
    public class windowDisplay extends Application

{

    // Variable declarations
    private String[] fileArray = null;
    private String holdStr = "";
    private Stage mainWindow;
    private boolean matchFound = false;
    private int count = 1;
    private int lineItems = 1;
    private double totalAmount = 0.0;
    private double subTotal = 0.0;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {

        // OMITTED CODE

        // These TextFields show the output depending on the input TextField's.
        itemInfoOutput.setDisable(true);
        orderSubtotalOutput.setDisable(true);

        // Process item button.
        processItem.setText("Process Item #" + count);
        processItem.setMinWidth(106);
        processItem.setOnAction(e ->
        {

            int numItems = Integer.parseInt(numItemInput.getText());
            lineItems = numItems;
            String bookIDs = bookIdInput.getText();
            int qtyItems = Integer.parseInt(qtyItemInput.getText());

            // Read file and check for Book ID
            fileArray = bookStoreIO.readFile(bookIDs);

            // Loop through array to find match or no matches
            for(int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++)
            {
                // If there is a match in book ID
                if (fileArray[i].equals(bookIDs))
                {
                    double price = Double.parseDouble(fileArray[i + 2]); // Price is in the i+2 position
                    double discount = calculateDiscount(qtyItems);
                    totalAmount = calculatePrice(qtyItems, price);
                    itemInfoOutput.setText(fileArray[i] + " " + fileArray[i + 1] + " " + "$" + price + " " +
                            qtyItems + " " + discount + "%" + " " + "$" + df.format(totalAmount));

                    // Disable processItem Button if there is a match and enable confirmItem Button
                    processItem.setDisable(true);
                    confirmItem.setDisable(false);

                    matchFound = true;
                }
            }

            if(matchFound == false)
                System.out.println("No match found!");

        });
    }

    // OMITTED CODE


    // This method calculates the discount depending on the quantity of items
    public static double calculateDiscount(int inputQty){return null;}

    // This methdod calculates the price with the discount
    public static double calculatePrice(int inputQty, double price){return null;}

}
```

This class reads the file and returns an array with the contents of that file (once split by the ", " delimitter).

```
public class bookStoreIO
{

    // This method reads the input file "inventory.txt" and saves it into an array.
    public static String[] readFile(String stringIn)
    {
        try
        {
            String nextLine;
            String[] fIn;

            // Read file
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.txt"));

            while((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                fIn = nextLine.split(", "); // Split when ", " is seen
                if(stringIn.equalsIgnoreCase(fIn[0]))
                {
                    br.close(); // Close file
                    return fIn; // Return array
                }

            }

        }

        // Just in case file isn't found
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I apologize if this seems messy, I'm still new to JavaFX and Java programming.
If you think more code is needed, please let me know!

EDIT: I improved some variable naming and removed the for loop. I'm still having trouble checking when there isn't a match.

```
public class windowDisplay extends Application

{

       // Variable declarations
private String[] fileArray = null;
private Stage mainWindow;
private boolean matchFound = false;
private int count = 1;
private int lineItems = 1;
private double totalAmount = 0.0;
private double subTotal = 0.0;

private int itemQty = 0;
private int idBook = 0;
private String bookTitle = "";
private double bookPrice = 0.0;
private double discountAmount = 0.0;
private String resultOrder = "";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {

        // OMITTED CODE

        // These TextFields show the output depending on the input TextField's.
        itemInfoOutput.setDisable(true);
        orderSubtotalOutput.setDisable(true);

          // Process item button.
    processItem.setText("Process Item #" + count);
    processItem.setMinWidth(106);
    processItem.setOnAction(e ->
    {

        int numItems = Integer.parseInt(numItemInput.getText());
        lineItems = numItems;
        String bookIDs = bookIdInput.getText();
        itemQty = Integer.parseInt(qtyItemInput.getText());

        // Read file and check for Book ID
        fileArray = bookStoreIO.readFile(bookIDs);
        idBook = Integer.parseInt(fileArray[0]);
        bookTitle = fileArray[1];
        bookPrice = Double.parseDouble(fileArray[2]);

        discountAmount = calculateDiscount(itemQty);
        totalAmount = calculatePrice(itemQty, bookPrice);
        itemInfoOutput.setText(idBook + " " + bookTitle + " $" + bookPrice + " " + itemQty + " " + discountAmount
        + "%  $" + df.format(totalAmount));


        itemInfo.setText("Item #" + count + " info:");

        processItem.setDisable(true);
        confirmItem.setDisable(false);
        matchFound = true;

        if(matchFound == false)
            System.out.println("not found");
    });

    // OMITTED CODE


    // This method calculates the discount depending on the quantity of items
    public static double calculateDiscount(int inputQty){return null;}

    // This method calculates the price with the discount
    public static double calculatePrice(int inputQty, double price){return null;}

}
```

I'm also having trouble saving

```
itemInfoOutput.setText(idBook + " " + bookTitle + " $" + bookPrice + " " + itemQty + " " + discountAmount
        + "%  $" + df.format(totalAmount));
```

into an String or String array to print out a list of all the corresponding matches (along with their book ID, book Title, book Price, quantity, discount , and total price).

An example is shown below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsCpF.png)

EDIT 2: [The right box is the main GUI. The bottom left box is what shows up when a wrong book is entered (on the 2nd order). The top left is the length of the array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBeGZ.png)

```
// Process item button.
    processItem.setText("Process Item #" + count);
    processItem.setMinWidth(106);
    processItem.setOnAction(e ->
    {

        int numItems = Integer.parseInt(numItemInput.getText());
        lineItems = numItems;
        String bookIDs = bookIdInput.getText();
        itemQty = Integer.parseInt(qtyItemInput.getText());

        // Read file and check for Book ID
        fileArray = bookStoreIO.readFile(bookIDs);

        for(int i=0; i<fileArray.length; i++)
            System.out.println(fileArray[i]);
        if(fileArray.length >= 3)
        {
            idBook = Integer.parseInt(fileArray[0]);
            bookTitle = fileArray[1];
            bookPrice = Double.parseDouble(fileArray[2]);

            discountAmount = calculateDiscount(itemQty);
            totalAmount = calculatePrice(itemQty, bookPrice);
            resultOrder = itemInfoOutput.getText();

            itemInfoOutput.setText(idBook + " " + bookTitle + " $" + bookPrice + " " + itemQty + " " + discountAmount
                    + "%  $" + df.format(totalAmount));
            resultOrder = idBook + " " + bookTitle + " $" + bookPrice + " " + itemQty + " " + discountAmount
             + "% $" + df.format(totalAmount);



            itemInfo.setText("Item #" + count + " info:");

            processItem.setDisable(true);
            confirmItem.setDisable(false);
        }
        else
            alertBox.confirmDisplay("Book ID " + idBook + " not in file");
    });
```

Comment: in `bookStoreIO`, try `return new String[0];` instead of `return null`.  You may not have a null reference to an array and attempt to determine it's length.

Comment: You're doing the "matching" code twice: it's implemented in your `bookStoreIO.readFile(String)` methods, which returns the *matching* book (represented as an array of Strings), if there is one, or null otherwise. Then you seem to iterate through that array (which actually represents the single book) again, looking for a match. You can get rid of the `for` loop in the `start()` method... just check if `fileArray` (which, again, is your book) is null...

Comment: Part of your problem here is that it's not clear what things represent. If you create a `Book` class with `int id`, `String title`, and `double price` fields, instead of using a `String[]` to represent that, it will be much clearer what you are doing. If you also name your method so it is descriptive of what its actual functionality is (e.g. `findBookById(int bookID)` instead of `readFile(...)`), it will help even more.

Comment: Thank you guys for your input! It seems like Ian Mc's suggestion worked for now. James_D, I'll look into your input and update if necessary. Thanks again!

Comment: Now that you have changed your code, you need a new way to handle a match not found.  After `fileArray = bookStoreIO.readFile(bookIDs);`, the next line should be something like `if (fileArray.length == 3)` { ... process; matchFound = true; } .. if (matchfound == false) { ... }.  What is the issue with the String?

Comment: Is there a reason why fileArray.length == 3 means that the match is true? As for the String, I want the inputs/output of itemInfoOutput into a String. It’s going to print whenever the “View Order” Button is clicked. So If I input order 1, I can view my order. When I input order 2, I can see my previous order and the new order and so on (until your order number is reached, thus you’ll have all your orders like in the example pic).

Comment: The length of `String[]` returned from `readFile` is based on a `split(", ")` so you are right - but you seem to use the first three elements of that array.  Maybe `fileArray.length >= 3` is better?  For the String, should you first run `String s = itemInfoOutput.getText()`, and then `s = s + "\n" + ... new info `.  This way you keep appending data to what was there previously.

Comment: @Ian MC, I was able to get the String to work! I’m still having troubles with the no match though. It basically just saves whatever book was first entered for the first order. So out of 2 orders, if order 1 book ID is 44444 and order 2 book ID is incorrect (not in the file), it will just print the first book ID as wrong instead of the 2nd order book ID. I’m sorry if this sounds a bit confusing. I believe it has to do with the return new String[0] but returning null doesn’t work. I also did if (fileArray.length == 3) {...do match process..) else{System.out.println(idBook + "not found in file")}

Comment: I don't understand (sorry).  In `readFile(String stringIn)`,  you `return fIn` if there is a match, or `new String[0]` if there is no match.  In the first case, the length of the array should be at least 3.  In the second case (not found) the length should be zero.  So ... what is the length returned in both cases (44444, and the other not on file).  What specific field is wrong?  I worry that the length of the array is larger than 3 because the split by comma might produce more fields than 3.  Can you print the array length to verify what is being returned?

Comment: @IanMc, I've updated the post to show the length of the array (I believe I did) and the pop-up box with the book ID (It should show "Book ID 32421212 not in file").

Comment: In the else where you `alertBox.confirmDisplay(..)` you use the variable `idBook`.  But `idBook` is only updated when a book is found.  Should you be using `bookIDs` instead?  Or should you set `idBook = bookIDs` before looking up the book?

Comment: @IanMc Oh wow... It should be bookIDs. Thank you so much for all your help. I seriously appreciate!!

Comment: You are welcome Fernando.  Cheers.